# Can you use OctoPrint on an Ender 5 pro with the stock firmware?

Tags: firmware, creality-ender-5, octoprint

Is it possible to use OctoPrint with an Ender 5 Pro that is still using the factory default firmware (any version) from Creality, or is changing the firmware an absolute pre requisite for even basic functionality.

This is for a situation where there are a dozen Ender 5 printers on lease hire, and no unauthorised modifications are permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OctoPrint is a print server which works independently from the controller board hardware. It simply sends commands to the printer. If you have a USB socket on the controller board and know the communication speed you can connect the printer to OctoPrint.

It will not work if the printer has a faulty or no USB connection. From an internet search it appears that the economical Ender hardware does have some issues with USB, but in theory you should be able to connect.

You only need to flash the Ender 5 controller board if you want to use Klipper firmware and use the OctoPrint Klipper plugin.

Here is a video showing how to setup OctoPrint in conjunction with an Ender 5:

Comment: I'm  at that pi case because, mounted on a printer, it's just asking for screws, nuts, clips, etc. that get dropped during maintenance or rattle loose to fall on the pi and short something out.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE, indeed, also not my choice! I once wrecked a Pi because a cooling element had come loose and caused a short circuit...