# New to OctoPrint, how to interface with Marlin Ender 3 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, octoprint

I plan on adding OctoPrint or mainsail to an Ender 3 Pro running Marlin 2.
As I understand it, the OctoPrint on the Pi runs klipper, which then feeds commands to the Ender 3 Marlin via the USB port.

Is the klipper advantage of speed and quality going to get lost going through Marlin (32-bit board)?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Can you use OctoPrint on an Ender 5 pro with the stock firmware?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/18938/can-you-use-octoprint-on-an-ender-5-pro-with-the-stock-firmware)?